# Optional claims in access token of azure missing for in_corp, vnet etc

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have been trying to get accesstoken with flag of in_corp and vent of the company within access token. I have added optional claims in manifest file, however it is not coming in access token.

```
"accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "in_corp",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "vnet",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "fwd",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "nickname",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }

        ],
```

Comment: The claims will be included when there is a value for it. Did you login in from the corporate network? `in_corp` claim isn't included.

Comment: Yes, I am in corporate network only. From office network I have been checking the token. Is there anything in Azure AD security settings that needs to be checked?

Comment: These are v2 optional claims. Are you sure your API is issuing v2 access tokens?

Comment: I am but new to this side of technique, where should I ensure whether I am using V1 or V2? if we are using V1, what are the steps to get the token from V2 then?

Answer (score 0):

> From office network I have been checking the token. Is there anything
>   in Azure AD security settings that needs to be checked?

No, there is nothing else needed to be done to get the optional claims. If there is a value for it, it will exit in the token. Your company must have configured ADFS, and your account is Synchronized to azure ad.

> where should I ensure whether I am using V1 or V2?

You can check the value of `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in manifest. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference) for the details.

> if we are using V1, what are the steps to get the token from V2 then?

You can find the v1.0 and v2.0 optional claims set [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set).

In conclusion, though you added the optional claims, you still didn't get these claims since there are no values mapped with them.

Comment: You mentioned in conclusion there are no values mapped. What that means? Do I need to do anything else as well?

Comment: What I need to set for your last line "you still didn't get these claims since there are no values mapped with them"